# Different Timestamp Header Value When Request Service After 8 PM

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter

I have some strange problem here, I need to send the current time in milisecond from android to authorize all user when try to request an API. My problem is, when I try to compare the header request and time server, it have some different, about 12 hours, and it happens after 8 PM everyday. When I try to call the API next morning, the header send correct timestamp with the server time.

Result After 8 PM

```
Time Request Header :  1639618812
Server Time         :  1639662014
Max 5 Minutes       :  1639662314
Min 5  Minutes      :  1639661714
```

This the result I tried just recently

```
Time Request Header :  1639704110
Server Time         :  1639704111
Max 5 Minutes       :  1639704411
Min 5 Minutes       :  1639703811
```

This is how I generated timestamp with flutter

```
  static String createXTimestamp() {
    DateTime test = DateTime.parse("1970-01-01 00:00:00");
    String now = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now().toUtc());
    var tStamp = DateTime.parse(now).millisecondsSinceEpoch - test.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    return tStamp.toString().substring(0,10);
  }
```

This is how it processed in NodeJs

```
  const dateNow =  Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    var max5 = dateNow + 300;
    var min5 = dateNow - 300;
    var time = req.headers.time;
    if(time >= min5 && time <= max5)
        //always return false
    else
        res.json({error_code: 401, message: "Unauthorized User"});
```

This really confuse me, so I really need some help here. Thank you.

Comment: Can you consider current utc time instead of current local time? As the utc time do not get daylight savings and is the same irrespective of the server and user location

Comment: @Ramesh Yeah, I intended to use UTC time instead of local, but maybe I miss something in the code that parse the local time instead of UTC. On the server side, `Date().getTime` is already in UTC from what I read on the documentation, so maybe the problem is on the `createXTimestamp()`

Comment: If you need UTC time, be explicit in the server and client about it. If you run the code in a server which is configured differently, then it may give the local time as configured in the server unless you set it up explicitly in elsewhere in your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a timezone bug. I don't think the `createXTimestamp` is doing the correct thing. There's a few timezone bugs in there, where the precision of the timezone is getting lost, and replaced with local timezone.

Also, you say "milliseconds since epoch" -- the `.substring(0,10)` is stripping off the milliseconds, and on the node side you divide by 1000 to get seconds as well.

If the goal is to return seconds since epoch, I don't think you need the `test` variable at all, and you can replace all of that function with the following:

```dart
static String createXTimestamp() {
  return DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString().substring(0, 10);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will test it tonight, hope its working.